# Change Date format in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, date-formatting, datefield

I have a date field called "birthdate" and property called "lifespan" in a django model.

**Field**

```
birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Property**

```
@property
def lifespan(self):
    return '%s - present' % self.birthdate
```

Currently lifespan returns the date in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

How can I changed this date format to "mm/dd/yyyy"?

I know how to do it in a django template with a filter but wanted to see if there was a similar "filter" that I can use in a Django model.

I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For full control, use [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
@property
def lifespan(self):
    return '%s - present' % self.birthdate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

`strftime` doesn't have all the formatting options that Django's `date` filter does, so if you want one of those you could call the filter as a function:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date

@property
def lifespan(self):
    return '%s - present' % date(self.birthdate, "n/j/Y")
```

That would omit the leading zeros, and would let you use your `DATE_FORMAT` settings variable or other predefined options.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe override the admin:

Say, the model is called PersonDetail,
then in admin.py

```
class PersonDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {'input_formats': ('%m/%d/%Y',)},
    }
```

Comment: That affects what input formats the admin understands, but the field would still be stored as a date or datetime and rendered using the implied `str` when string interpolated.

Comment: Got it. I has used something like that on a form field, and thought it would work. Thanks !!