# How can I define the date format in models in django?

Tags: django, date, django-models

I'm defining a date variable inside my model `AccessRecord` using `DateField` attribute and I've tried every possible thing to define it. But every time a new error arises. Sometimes it says "Date is not defined" sometimes "Date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format" during migration.
Can someone give me a permanent solution for this? I'm using django 2.1.7.

I've tried `default=''` and `default=blank` and quite of few others

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Comment: What do you want the default to be? None or "today"?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/20229198/4107823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficent

```
from django.db import models

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

And for the formatting stuff use the @property mentioned in [stackoverflow.com/q/20229198/4107823](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20229198/4107823) as commented by PetarP